# How can i Load a Xdocument online who needs a username and a password

Tags: xml, xamarin.android, xdoc

Is it possible to Load an XML File who has a password and a username like so:

```
XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.load("htt://myApp/MyTestFile", "Username", "passwordtest");
```

Please help, I am hanging on that last point for my app.

Comment: Why did you use this method? Are you need restore user message from a file that keep in your project? If so, you could use [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#GetSharedPreferences) to store and restore these message.

Comment: I am Already using sharedPreferences but not for that.
i have to load the Xml File and without username and password i dont have
access to that file

Comment: You could see the [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.load(v=vs.110).aspx) there's no such method, and what's you mean "without username and password i dont have access to that file", could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Yes i know that there is no Methode at Xdocument but thats my problem. :)
If i try to reach the Xml File in my Browser i have an Authetification popup with Username and Password and without this two i dont see anyithing.
and If i try to load the Xdocument in my app without this two i get that error:
"WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can i Load a Xdocument online who needs a username and a password

You could set the [Credentials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver.credentials(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the [XmlUrlResolver](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlurlresolver(v=vs.110).aspx), as the document said :

> Sets credentials used to authenticate web requests.

Then use [XmlReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader(v=vs.110).aspx) and [XmlReaderSettings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings(v=vs.110).aspx) for the `XDocument`.

Something like this :

```
XmlUrlResolver res = new XmlUrlResolver();
res.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

XmlReaderSettings set = new XmlReaderSettings();
set.XmlResolver = res;

XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create("htt://myApp/MyTestFile", set));
```

Comment: best Man thank you verry much this works absolutly fine for me