# Using XmlUriResolver to provide credentials to remote share

Tags: c#, xml, winpe

Thank you in advance for any and all help.

I have seen several post on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47884894/how-can-i-load-a-xdocument-online-who-needs-a-username-and-a-password) and other sites on the net (including [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlresolver.credentials?view=netframework-4.7.2)), but none seeming to help resolve my issue.

I am working on a project that connects to a xml file on a remote file share from WinPE.  I have used suggestions from another post on SO about using the XmlUriResolver class to "moderate" success.

The issue I am currently being faced with is either a "Access Denied" error (several attempts to modify the XmlUriResolver.Credentials class) or a complete failure without any reason for failure.  I am assuming it is going to be another "Access Denied" error, but my try/catch (Exception e) isn't capturing the reason.

Below is a snippet and relevant part of the method I am trying to implement:

```
relativeSysData = relativeSysData.Replace(@"\", "/");
SysdataXml = $"file://{_globaldata.Server}/{_globaldata.Share}/{relativeSysData}";

XmlUrlResolver XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver();
XmlResolver.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(_UserName, 
                                                _Password);

XmlReaderSettings xmlSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlSettings.XmlResolver = XmlResolver;
LogWriter.WriteLogFile((int)LogWriter.EventID.Xml, (int)LogWriter.EventType.Info,
                      $"Connecting to (remote) System information store at: {SysdataXml}");

xDoc = XDocument.Load(XmlReader.Create(SysdataXml, xmlSettings));
if (xDoc == null)
{
    LogWriter.WriteLogFile((int)LogWriter.EventID.XmlError, (int)LogWriter.EventType.Error,
                          $"Unable to connect to the (remote) data store located at: {SysdataXml}");
    deploy = false;
    capture = false;
    return result;
}
```

This part of the method is specific to accessing the remote data.  I have a try/catch statement encompassing all of the method.

If I have an open connection to the Network Share, the method will work flawlessly, but will cause the application this application starts to fail - due to an open connection already.

I have a possible alternative to work round this solution but will cost extra lines of code.

Any help in resolving this matter, without resorting to WNetAddConnection() will be gratefully received

Kind Regards

Richie

N.B.  I am aware that this is an authentication issue.

Comment: if (xDoc == null) has been modified to if (string.IsEmptyorNull(xDoc..ToString()))

Comment: With  Windows never use a username and password to access a shared folder.  It will not work.  Use default credential if you have access to the driver using an explorer : XmlResolver.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; or XmlResolver.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;

Comment: Default credentials will not work.  I'm operating from WinPe (Win 10 ver 1809).  The credentials are "User"  and without building my own file explorer (or using a third party design for WinPE).  I can connect using WNetAddConnection(), but would rather not, as the implications of it failing to close the connection will fail the entire remote build.

Comment: Can you access the shared drive using a Window Explorer?  Windows doesn't allow remote connections without a Group setup to allow a connection from another PC.

Comment: I'm programming for Windows Pre-Installation Environment (WinPE), there are no Explorers, whether Windows or Internet - the application works a dream in the full version of Windows, but is failing in the mini-os that WinPE is.  The Remote computer is setup to allow remote connections.  The Application that this one starts relies upon WNetAddConnection to transfer 4GB+ file sizes.  That is why I would like to utilise a method like this to connect to the UNC file path.  My apologies - I may not have explained it fully in my question post.

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  If an explorer works then a user name and password are not needed and default credentials are being used.

Comment: When debugging from Windows 10, it works a dream.

Comment: When testing in Windows PE, it fails - so this is an authentication issue,  Following  information given at the Microsoft Docs link, it should work as it states that the XmlUriResolver class works with the "file://" pre-fix of a uri.  Looking at my log files, .net translates the "file://server/share/path1/path2/file.xml" into it's UNC equivalent,  it just fails to connect.

Comment: You still didn't answer the question!!!  Get it working with a windows explorer and then it should work with default credentials.  You have an issue with the User Accounts allowing a remote connection.

Comment: Fix the registry : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/9ea481ea-9f18-4876-b4b9-419d9b3774d6/windows-pe-30-cant-map-a-drive-with-domain-account?forum=w7itproinstall

Comment: Please listen, I know this is an authentication issue.  Windows Explorer means nothing in the environment I am testing in.  It is not even part of the mini-os (WinPE).  When the application is debugged in the full version of Windows 10, it works - and yes I can see the share point in explorer here.  The default credentials of WinPE will not work, as the default user of WinPE is "User", although it runs with administrative access.  This account will not be available at all on my PC, or in any network that it may be introduced into.

Comment: Looking at the "Fix the registry" comment, I have an application that connects successfully using the WnetAddConnection2() API, to facilitate large file transfers.  EDIT: after applying the said Lm change - still not effective.

Comment: We are both saying basically the same thing.  I don't use WinPE, but know that the PC has to allow for a drive to be shared for the WinPE to be able to connect.  The Windows10 machine is in a group that allows it access to the shared drive while WinPE is not in the group.  Using a username and password is not going to work unless a group is properly setup.

Comment: The group is correctly setup.  As I have stated on many occasions now, I have a second application that uses WNetAddConnection2() API to map a network share to a local drive successfully - so the permissions are correctly set.  I am trying not to use this approach with this app - as if fails to disconnect, it will generate a failure in the second application.

Comment: So is the working application using a default credential; or user name and password?  Is the working application using the same user account?  Try to understand the differences between the working and non-working applications to help understand the issue.

Comment: User name and password loaded from a local configuration file.  Username passed as Domain\Username.  I have tried both this and as just Username in the XMLRulResolver class.  I have tried adding the Domain into the domain property and nothing connects, unless I have an action connection already.

Comment: Maybe a service isn't started automatically in the WindPE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After research into how the XmlUrlResolver class works, I think that it may be referencing/accessing API's that are not included within the WinPE API framework.

After testing, I have used the WNetAddConnection2() API to connect to the Server and authenticate before anything happens, ensuring that the local name of the NETRESOURCE structure is left null, and that DisplayType is set to Server.

```
public static int ConnectToServer()
    {
        int result = 0;

        var _netresource = new NetResource()
        {
            scope = _ResourceScope.GlobalNetwork,
            ResourceType = _ResourceType.Any,
            DisplayType = _ResourceDisplayType.Server,
            RemoteName = $@"\\{Program._globaldata.Server}"
        };

        string _username = $@"{Program._globaldata.Server}\RemoteDKBuild";
        string _passsword = "Hic3nuasno6epyndtenars4yDifrts";

        var _connectiontype = (int)_ConnectionType.Interactive | (int)_ConnectionType.Temporary;

        LogWriter.WriteLogFile((int)LogWriter.EventID.NetMan, (int)LogWriter.EventType.Info,
                                $@"Attempting to connect to: \\{_netresource.RemoteName}");
        result = WNetAddConnection2(_netresource, _passsword, _username, _connectiontype);
        var res = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        if (result !=0)
        {
            LogWriter.WriteLogFile((int)LogWriter.EventID.NetMan, (int)LogWriter.EventType.Error,
                                    $@"Failed to connect to: \\{_netresource.RemoteName}, Return Result: {result.ToString()}, Win32 Error Code: {res.ToString()}");
            result = res;
        }
        else
        {
            LogWriter.WriteLogFile((int)LogWriter.EventID.NetMan, (int)LogWriter.EventType.Info,
                                    $@"Connection to: \\{_netresource.RemoteName} has been successfull.");
        }

        return result;
    }

[DllImport("mpr.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int WNetAddConnection2(NetResource netResource, string password, string username, int flags);
```